# Passing Text to Shortcut via Command Line Arguments

Tags: command-line, shortcuts-app

###### Problem

I want to run a Shortcut from the command line and include Unicode text as a part of the command. I want to do something like: `shortcuts run "My Notification Shortcut" "My Text Input"`

[image: macOS Notification Dialog]

According to the [Shortcuts Docs](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts-mac/run-shortcuts-from-the-command-line-apd455c82f02/6.0/mac/13.0):

> Running shortcuts from the command line is no different from running shortcuts in the Shortcuts app—you can pass documents, images, text, and more.

###### shortcuts -h:

```
shortcuts run <shortcut-name-or-identifier> [--input-path <input-path> ...] [--output-path <output-path>] [--output-type <output-type>]
```

This seems to imply that the text **must** be included as a file. This works:

`shortcuts run "Test" -i "/Users/Dave/My Text.txt"`

and I want to do this:

`shortcuts run "Test" "My Text Input"`

Having to save the text to a file seems like an unnecessary step.

###### Question:

Is it possible to pass a text object as a command line arg directly to a Shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's possible after all using the bash operator `<<<`. This shell command works as intended:

`shortcuts run "Test Alert" <<< "My Text Input"`

[image: Sample Notification with passed text]

###### "man bash"

> Here Strings
> A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
>  <<<word
> ```
>
> The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

Update 1: per @Martin R.'s comment above, the following construction also works.

`echo "My Text Input" | shortcuts run "Test Alert"`

Answer (score 0):

According the the shortcuts man page ([`man shortcuts`](https://ss64.com/osx/shortcuts.html)) input to be passed must be a file or set of files:

> An input file (or set of files) to be processed by the shortcut. Wildcards accepted.

Unfortunately, you cannot pass a text *object* (a variable, for example) as an argument to the `shortcuts` command.  It has to be a file.

Comment: Weird (but not overly so) that the man page and the docs don't match.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Unaccepted answer because it turns out that it is possible.