# Reading Command Line Arguments for Shortcut

Tags: command-line, shortcuts-app

**Problem**: I want to run a Shortcut from the command line that outputs a list of reminders that have a specific tag e.g. `shortcuts run ReminderTag <<< "myTag"`. However, I'm unable to figure out how to setup the Shortcut inside of the Shortcut app to accept input from the command line.

From this [previous post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/454959/passing-text-to-shortcut-via-command-line-arguments) it seems that there is indeed a way to get pass in commandline arguments but I'm not sure which Action I should be using inside of the Shortcut I am creating to accept this.

I've currently tried

- `Shortcut Input` but that doesn't have any options for text input
- `Ask Each Time` but this bring up a prompt despite me passing in arguments from the command line
- I've also found an alternate syntax for passing in arguments `echo "myTag" | shortcuts run ReminderTag -i -` but this also brings up the prompt

**Question**:
What Action should I use inside of the Shortcut app to accept command line arguments?